# Scale text over image in custom imageview

Tags: android, text, imageview

I have written a custom imageview to show a credit card. To create the credit card I have a base image and I have setters to set the PAN, Card holder, expiry. This text needs to be drawn on top of the base card image. My problem is maintaining the position and size of the text so that it will always look correct no matter the changing size of the base image. The only thing I can rely on is the aspect ratio of the image being the same as a normal credit card.

My custom ImageView

```
public class CardView extends ImageView {
private String mPan = "4321 0123 4567 8910";
private String mExpiry = "01/16";
private String mCardholder = "MR JOHN SMITH";
private float mPanTextSize = 22;
private float mOtherTextSize = 14;
private Paint mPanPaint = new Paint();
private Paint mCardholderPaint = new Paint();

public CardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    initCardView();
}

public CardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initCardView();
}

public CardView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initCardView();
}

private final void initCardView() {
    mPanPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    mPanPaint.setShadowLayer(1, 1, 1, 0xAA000000);
    mPanPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPanPaint.setTextSize(mPanTextSize * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
    mPanPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
    mCardholderPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    mCardholderPaint.setShadowLayer(1, 1, 1, 0xAA000000);
    mCardholderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mCardholderPaint.setTextSize(mOtherTextSize * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
    mCardholderPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
    setPadding(0,0,0,0);
    //setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    float panLength = mPanPaint.measureText(mPan);
    float x = (getWidth() - panLength)/2;
    float y =  -mPanPaint.ascent() + (getHeight() * 0.46f);
    canvas.drawText(mPan, x, y, mPanPaint);
    x = (getWidth() - panLength)/1.5f;
    y = y - mCardholderPaint.ascent();
    canvas.drawText(mExpiry, x, y, mCardholderPaint);
    y = y - mCardholderPaint.ascent();
    canvas.drawText(mCardholder, x, y, mCardholderPaint);

    //super.onDraw(canvas);
}

public void setPan(String pan) {
    mPan = pan;
    invalidate();
}

public String getPan() {
    return mPan;
}

public void setExpiry(String expiry) {
    mExpiry = expiry;
    invalidate();
}

public String getExpiry() {
    return mExpiry;
}

public void setCardholder(String cardholder) {
    mCardholder = cardholder;
    invalidate();
}

public String getCardholder() {
    return mCardholder;
}
}
```

So sometimes this looks ok but as you get to 10 inch screens the text is way too small, right in the center of the image (imagine looking at a credit card but the number only takes up the space of the middle 8 digits), and as you get to small screens the text is too big, going right up to the image sides or past them.

Any solutions? Any explanation why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the text sizes dependent on the size of your image.

try to experiment with different values for yourPanFactor and yourCardholderFactor until you get the desired result

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    if (changed) {
        final int height = bottom-top;  
        mPanPaint.setTextSize(height*yourPanFactor);
        mCardholderPaint.setTextSize(height*yourCardholderFactor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Renard, I tried what you suggested but the result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make this work in this lines of code

```
if (imageView.getWidth() <= resource.getWidth()) {
           ratio = (float) resource.getWidth() / (float) imageView.getWidth();
     } else {
           ratio = (float) imageView.getWidth() / (float) resource.getWidth();
     }
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paint.setTextSize(editText.getTextSize() * ratio);
```

Note that the editText has the default text size which is 14 sp.

I hope it help you. and correct me if am wrong